# Questions regarding Flutter Web and Django Rest API

Tags: django, flutter, django-rest-framework, flutter-web

I am trying to make this blog website for my university, I am using flutter for the frontend and DRF for the backend. I have some questions regarding these.

1. Do I need to host my DRF API in order to fetch data from the server? will it work if I use the free version of heroku?
2. Is there a way I can access the Django admin panel from the flutter frontend? like, assign new users using the admin panel that Django offers?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes it needs to be hosted if you want to fetch data from the server in production. The free version of Heroku is an excellent option for this.